# Configure Spring application deployed in AWS Elastic Beanstalk to use SSL

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I deployed successfully Spring application into AWS Elastic Beanstalk which us going to be used as Rest endpoint by Angular app. I want to encrypt the communication between Angular and Spring with SSL.
What is the best approach for that? Use AWS Load balancer or use some Java code to allow only SSL requests? What solution do you use?

If it's possible I would like to use different Spring profiles for local development and production use. So enable and disable this functionality into application.yml will be the best option.

Comment: Angular is front-end and Spring is backend on EB?

Comment: No Angular is deployed on Cloudfront

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the generate SSL certificate on add it to ELB so that your Rest endpoint is protected. And for Angular website which is deployed on Cloudfront you can do the same and generate the SSL certificate from AWS Certificate manager and add the SSL while creating the CloudFront distribution. This way your Rest endpoint will be protected and the Website too.

Comment: I see one big issue here: the traffic between load balancer and Spring application running as AWS Elastic Beanstalk instance is not encrypted. Correct me if I'm wrong. Is there any solution for that?

Comment: You can add them in the same VPC and protect it using the Security Group settings.

Comment: If you are using SSL then it should be encrypted.

Comment: @PeterPenzov That's correct. Traffic between LB and your EB instance will be HTTP, not HTTPs. This is usual practice, unless you have a very specific reason to enforce HTTPS between LB and the instance.

Comment: Yes, I want to use this setup in future PCI-DSS env. For that reason I see there is Government cloud in AWS. But now I want to see how to do this here. Ant idea for a a solution.

Comment: You can do that while creating the ELB, refer to this link below:
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elb-redirect-http-to-https-using-alb/

Comment: @PeterPenzov Will you award the bounty to me then? I don't know how the bounty rewards work so thats why asking.

Answer (score 2):

As indicated in the answer provided by Muzaffar, in a general use case the use of a load balancer for SSL termination is probably the more convenient way to setup your service.

It frees your EB instance for the task of SSL processing, terminating SSL as mentioned. In addition, you can redirect your HTTP to HTTPS traffic if required, and it is fully integrated with ACM for your certificate management tasks.

It seems that your main concern has to do with the traffic between the load balancer and the beanstalk instance.

As pointed out by Martin, the usual practice is that the traffic between the LB and the EB instance will be HTTP, not HTTPS.

Having said that, AWS allows you to encrypt the traffic between the LB and EB as well, getting end to end HTTPS, by configuring your services properly. On one hand, you still need [to configure your LB to terminate SSL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/configuring-https-elb.html) and, on the other, you basically need to define the right `.ebextension`s depending on your LB type. This [AWS document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/configuring-https-endtoend.html) describe in detail the whole process.